# What is the history of the Molly, which became the USS Reprisal

Tags: american-revolution, naval, ships

According to Wikipedia, the [USS Reprisal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Reprisal_(1776))

> ...was the first ship of what was to become the United States Navy to be
>   given the name promising hostile action in response to an offense.
>   Originally the merchantman brig Molly, she was purchased from Robert
>   Morris by the Marine Committee of the Continental Congress on March
>   28, 1776, renamed Reprisal, and placed under the command of Captain
>   Lambert Wickes.

Was the Molly the same ship to transport immigrants from Rotterdam to Philadelphia (early 1700s)?

Comment: I don't think you can count equality of two 18th century merchant ship names   to be proof of identity  of the ships themselves.  Especially with such an informal-sounding name as "Molly".  Now if the ship had been named "Pickled Cabbage is my Delight", the case might be different...

Comment: The most detail I have been able to find so far comes from [_Sea Raiders of the American Revolution: The Continental Navy in European Waters_
by E. Gordon Bowen-Hassell, Dennis Michael Conrad, Mark L. Hayes](https://books.google.com/books?id=9UfVBKrnqq4C&pg=PA1&dq=molly+robert+morris+reprisal&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj028eMsfjeAhVHXKwKHVDbCtAQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=molly%20robert%20morris%20reprisal&f=false) and another book (see next comment)...

Comment: (cont'd) See also [_American Revolution: The Definitive Encyclopedia and Document Collection (5 volumes)_, edited by Spencer C. Tucker](https://books.google.com/books?id=CyJrDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA1582&lpg=PA1582&dq=merchant+brig+molly+robert+morris+reprisal&source=bl&ots=Q_aqeOOxJ7&sig=nyBQKoLw4L4_GXJVl0-e-4pvKNc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFudf3r_jeAhXJsVQKHR9rCS0Q6AEwCnoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=merchant%20brig%20molly%20robert%20morris%20reprisal&f=false)